# Htaccess - Map dynamic URL query to a static file

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to map this dynamic query:

```
 /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mymail_form_css
```

to this static file:

```
 /wp-admin/mymail_form.css
```

What I've tried so far which doesn't seem to work is this htaccess code in /wp-admin/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=mymail_form_css
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mymail_form.css [L,R=301]
```

I've also tried placing that in the site's document root and no go.

I'm doing this for performance reasons. The dynamic query takes an excessive amount of time to generate a small bit of CSS which hardly ever changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it out. Got it to work by moving the css file to public_html (not really necessary), changing the htaccess code to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=mymail_form_css
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mymail_form.css? [L,R=301]
```

and moving the code to the document root's .htaccess

Carry on~